# Javascript - Not able to access index.jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Used [this link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/) to create index.jsp. It works fine if its under webapp, when I move the index.jsp to WEB-INF/jsp folder, its not working.

mvc-dispatcher-servlet is having correct mapping only.

```
    <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
```

Comment: share your bean config file

Comment: I have only created the maven project which has web.xml & mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml which has the below code, index.jsp. No other java code.

Comment: @Florian  mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml which has the below code......
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>
 <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>
</beans>

Comment: <web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
              org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app> web.xml has above code